# How do I fix this error I get when ever I try to mount my USB stick which has Ubuntu installed on it?

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive

I always get this error when I mount my PNY 8GB Stick onto my computer. It also shows two separate drives as shown here:

[image: DUPLICATE DRIVE PICTURE]

I also get this error mounting it always:

[image: WEIRD ERROR]

Comment: -t `iso9660` is incorrect. It should be -t `vfat`. Cheers, Al